# regular expression for number and spaces in the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate some forms and what I want to have is a regular expression that will allow numbers and spaces. The expression will not allow

```
1000 space space 00
```

but it will allow something like

```
space space space 10000
```

or

```
1000 space space space
```

I have tried this, but it's not what I want:

```
var filter = /^[0-9 ]+$/;
if(price.val() == "") 
    alert('vide');
else if(filter.test(price.val()))
    alert('number');
else 
    alert('no number');
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: i think i'm edited wrongly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^\s*\d+\s*$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/mX0xN3/3)**

[image]

Regex explanation from **[Hwnd](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5E%5Cs*%5Cd%2B%5Cs*%24&.submit=Explain%21&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)** tool:

```
^                        the beginning of the string
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
\d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
\s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                         more times)
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

Comment: Pretty sure "space" in the original post means the space character, not the word space.

Comment: The misunderstanding makes sense though. In the original post the `1000 space space 00` statements were not encased as code blocks. The editor put them in code blocks.

Comment: I removed the downvote. Your regex was fine given what you thought the user wanted... and now you've fixed that part too!

Comment: Also, thanks for the link. I know that there are lots of regex sites out there, but this one looks nice.

Comment: @MadPhysicist regex101 is an excellent site. You can try also debuggex.com that makes a good job too. And also an excellent tool that hwnd created http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl

Answer (score 4):

You could try

```
var filter = /^\s*[0-9]+\s*$/;
```

[`\s`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) is the whitespace character. You can replace it with  if you only want to specifically check for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this pattern helps `^ *[0-9]+ *$`